# RichMarker for Google Maps v3 - Click falls through marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using RichMarker for Google Maps v3 as found at https://googlemaps.github.io/js-rich-marker/reference.html

I have successfully been able to register clicking on the marker with this code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(this.richMarker, 'click', function(event) {
    console.log("click made on marker");
});
```

However the click also falls through the marker, so it registers a click on whatever falls behind it. ie the map, if it has a handler:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    console.log("click made on map");
});
```

Or a polygon if it is clickable.

How can I prevent this fall through click with RichMarker?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or at least a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see how you did it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to modify the library.

Find this part:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.markerContent_, 'click',   function(e) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(that, 'click');
});
```

and change it to

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.markerContent_, 'click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  google.maps.event.trigger(that, 'click');
});
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The click on map is still active.

Answer (score 1):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(richMarker, 'click', function(event) 
{
    // your stuff here

    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Just a variable issue, rename all the variable to "event"

Comment: This doesn't work for me either - `event` is undefined. Not a naming issue.