# Richmarker get event.LatLng on click google maps js api v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I applied fix as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29003120/richmarker-for-google-maps-v3-click-falls-through-marker) to richmarker.js

Once i use

```
my_rich_marker.addListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event); //undefined
}
```

What i need is to get `event.latLng` of richmarker within onclick function like it works with regular marker.

Answer (score 0):

The event argument passed into the "click" event for RichMarker is the argument from the browser's native click event, which doesn't have a `.latLng` property.

from [the RichMarker source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker/gh-pages/src/richmarker.js):

```
var that = this;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.markerContent_, 'click', function(e) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(that, 'click', e);
});
```

You have two options:

1. modify the RichMarker library to add the latLng property to the returned event.
2. calculate the associated latLng from the properties available in the browser's native click event.
3. set the latLng property of the returned event to `this.getPosition()` (based off of Dr.Molle's answer):

   ```
   google.maps.event.addListener(my_rich_marker, 'click', function(event) {
     event.latLng = this.getPosition();
     console.log(event.latLng.toUrlValue()); 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When you really want it ***like it works with regular marker***:

When you click on a regular marker the `latLng`-property of the event is equal to the `position` of the marker.

So all you would have to do is to retrieve the `position` of the RichMarker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(my_rich_marker,'click',function(e){
  console.log(this.getPosition());
});
```